# IPC between C and Node.js results in "TypeError: Unsupported fd type: UNKNOWN"

Tags: c, node.js, ipc

I am trying to setup inter-process communication between a simple C program and Node.js. The code below works mostly fine, however after some time (~5-10 Minutes) the Node.js application crashes with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Unsupported fd type: UNKNOWN
     at createHandle (net.js:70:9)
     at new Socket (net.js:209:20)
     at fs.open (/home/pi/src/components/named_pipe_receiver.ts:22:23)
     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

C:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int fd;
  char * fifo_name = "/tmp/fifo";

  mkfifo(fifo_name, 0666);

  char buff[20];
  time_t my_time;

  while (1) {
    fd = open(fifo_name, O_WRONLY);

    time(& my_time);
    strftime(buff, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(& my_time));
    write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));

    close(fd);
    usleep(10000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Node.js (v8.9.4):

```
const C = require('constants');
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');

function listen() {
  const fd = fs.openSync('/tmp/fifo', C.O_NONBLOCK | C.O_RDONLY);
  const socket = new net.Socket({ fd, readable: true, writable: false });

  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  socket.on('close', () => {
    fs.closeSync(fd);
    socket.end();
    socket.destroy();
    listen();
  });

  socket.on('error', () => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
}

listen();
```

Both programs are rewritten to post here, but they capture the essence of what I am trying to accomplish.

**Question 1:**
How can I fix my code so that the error message never appears again?

**Question 2:**
I feel like there is a better way to communicate between the two processes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Small update, it has run smoothly now for 2 hours after removing the `fs.close`, `socket.end` and `socket.destroy` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this error occur again after removing the lines that close the file and end the socket:

```
socket.on('close', () => {
  // fs.closeSync(fd);
  // socket.end();
  // socket.destroy();
  listen();
});
```

This seems to have fixed it!